# Having trouble copying a github repository onto my unix machine

Tags: github

I am trying to copy a github repository into my "documents" folder on my macbook pro but have continually received the error message below. I am brand new to github and am using it for the odin project. Any tips or tricks to work through this obstacle? Thank you.

Collins-MacBook-Pro:~ collinremmers$ cd documents
Cj-MacBook-Pro:documents cj01$ git clone git@github.com:cjremm01/git_test.git
Cloning into 'git_test'...
/Users/cj01/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: identifyfile
/Users/cj01/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: `identifyfile` is a typo for `IdentityFile`; fix your `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to clone it with the URL and not via SSH

```
git clone https://github.com/cjremm01/git_test
```

Comment: Or if you really need to connect via SSH, you can check this: https://technikales.com/quick-steps-to-connect-to-github-through-ssh-in-mac/  Although I would recomment to use github just cloning.